# Use presenters view on a portion of the screen

Tags: display, microsoft-powerpoint, tv

I am using PowerPoint 2016 using presenters view on a 48 inches TV.

My TV left portion has colored vertical lines running from top to bottom therefore I have to shift all my slides content to the right as the presenter view occupies the entire screen 48 inches.( I have over 100 slides )

Is there a way to use the middle to right portion of my TV using the presenters view so that it does not fill up the entire screen of my TV?

Any help will be appreciated

Sincerely,
Hamza

Comment: Why would you have the presenters view on the TV? Is the TV damaged? Why not fix the stripes?

Comment: Hi @Seth I am using my TV as a second monitor to present stuff therefore presenters view.

Yes the TV is damaged. 

It would costs nearly as much as purchasing a new TV to fix them. I'm just trying to use what I already have.

Comment: You might be able to change the master page and just reapply those changes to the other sheets. You could also check the ["Set Up Slide Show"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-Up-Slide-Show-05167760-e610-4115-81b7-60bdff85774b) options to set it up to run the presentation in a window, rather than full screen. As for [presenter view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-your-speaker-notes-privately-ccfa1894-e3ef-4955-9c3a-444d58248093?) that is an actual mode and you wouldn't want the presenter view (that is the one with time etc.) on your second display?